# Mysql query to get data from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, database

I have 2 following tables:

```
Users (user_id, user_name, ... )
Photo (photo_id, user_id, ...)
```

How can I get `photo_id`, by providing only `user_name`. Do I need to make 2 queries, first query to get user_id from Users table by providing user_name, and after I get user_id, i should perform second query to get photo_id by providing user_id.

**OR** this is not good approach, rather I should join the tables and get the photo_id by providing user-name with a single query? How that should be done ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you select them my user_id since I guess that each user_name has a unique user_id?

Comment: @Cristina, I get the username from URL with $_GET, and in url I want to have user_name eg. `?user=sudeep` instead of id, eg.`?user=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do that in a single query, using a join :

```
select Users.user_id, Photo.photo_id
from Photo
    inner join Users on Users.user_id = Photo.user_id
where Users.user_name = 'YOUR NAME HERE'
```

Note : I selected the `user_id`, as several users can have the same name *(maybe)*

Answer (score 0):

SELECT u.user_id, p.photo_id FROM users AS u INNER JOIN photo AS p ON u.user_id = p.user_id WHERE u.user_name = '$username';

Answer (score 0):

This is what joins are for:

```
select u.*, p.* from users u join photo p on p.user_id = u.user.id
where u.user_name = 'the name'
```

Making two queries in this case will decrease performance significantly because of the overhead of your source code submitting the query to the database engine, that query compiling etc.